# How to return multiple rows using Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am new to Stored Procedure. I have written a query to get multiple rows. But I am getting error like

> Error Code: 1172. Result consisted of more than one row.

Should I use CURSOR type?

Here my query and table structure.

My table structure is:

```
+---+------+------+---------+
|id | name | class| section |
+---+------+------+---------+
|1  |abc   |5     | A       |
|2  |cdef  |5     | B       |
|3  |hikl  |5     | A       |
|4  |xyz   |5     | A       |
+---+------+------+---------+
```

My Stored procedure query is

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `mulitiOut`(out namee VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
select name into @namee from mytable where section = A;
END
```

How can I return all the name related to section A.

Comment: You can't store multiple records in a single variable. Just select without putting anything in a variable

Comment: @juergend: how to use the data thus obtained. I wanted to do some computation on the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can return a result set directly from a procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `mulitiOut`()
BEGIN
 SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE section = A;
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function -

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) INTO @namee FROM mytable WHERE section = A;
```

As a workaround - create and fill another table -

```
INSERT INTO temp_table(name) SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE section = A;
```

Comment: In the above query out namee VARCHAR(50) is okay or should i do any changes ??

Comment: Of course, you should increase this length if needed. By the way, GROUP_CONCAT function is also limited, 1024 - is default length.

Comment: Yes, But i am getting all result in one column itself.. But i need in row wise !

Comment: If you need one value - use GROUP_CONCAT; only remember about limitations.

Comment: All names in one column it self with coma separated.. But i need as every name should be in different row..

Comment: Then look at workaround. You just should create an additional table for this purposes. Fill it in procedure and use in other scripts/queries.